# Jekyll - blog html is generated into several nested directories

Tags: jekyll

I am new to Jekyll and am currently following along with the [step by step](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/) tutorial to get acquainted with the stack.

My issue is that my blog html files which are generated to the `_site` directory end up in nested folders. The folders correspond with the date format required for the blog post markdown files.

Here is a visual of the file structure as it is now (only including relevant directories and files):

```
root/
|____ _posts/
|           2019-04-16-post-01.md
|           2019-04-16-post-02.md
|____ _site/
|__________2019/
|______________04/
|________________16/
|                  post-01.html
|                  post-02.html
|__________ assets/
|                 css/
|                    styles.css
|
|__________ blog.html
|__________ index.html
|
```

This means that the css file path which all html is using is incorrect for the blog posts. The path would have to be `../../../assets/css/styles.css`

Can anyone shed some light on why Jekyll generates the blog files nested like this and what the resolution may be?

Answer (score 1):

In the [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/default/), the default Jekyll configuration for the output permalink URL of posts is the [date](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#built-in-formats) style which is `/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title:output_ext`. The multiple `/` in the permalink is why you have lots of folders in your generated site.

To fix this, you could change the output permalink to something like `:year-:month-:day-:title:output_ext` so that you get something like `2019-04-16-post-01.html`. Or, you could link to assets using absolute paths instead of relative paths as seen in the [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#including-images-and-resources). Instead of `../../../assets/`, you could just use `/assets/` since you know the `assets` folder is at the root of your site.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was able to solve for this by adding a base url to my config file and using that for the css path. Your answer is also a great way to go about this as well.